# Does $0\to \mathbb Z^2\to H_1(X,A)\to \mathbb Z^{k-1}\to 0$ split?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, exact-sequence

Consider the following exact sequence: $0\to \mathbb Z^2\to H_1(X,A)\to \mathbb Z^{k-1}\to 0$.

How do I show that this splits?

By definition of splitting, I should have $H_1(X,A)= \mathbb Z^2 \oplus \mathbb Z^{k-1}=\mathbb Z^{k+1}$. But I don't understand how to show that this is the case here.

This came across while studying the relative homology groups $H_n(X,A)$  when $X$ is a torus and $A$ is a subcollection of $k$ points of $X$.

Comment: The sequence does split. Hint: Use the projectiveness of $\mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}-$module.

Comment: @Zerox: Thanks. I'm afraid I don't know the projective modules. Is there any other way?

Comment: Fix a generator set $\{ e_i \}_{1}^{k-1}$ of $\mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$. Choose an inverse image of $e_i$ (denoted as $w_i$) in $H_1(X,A)$. Try to prove that $h: \mathbb{Z}^{k-1} \rightarrow H_1(X,A): e_i \mapsto w_i$ is a well-defined embedding and that $H_1(X,A) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2} \oplus h(\mathbb{Z}^{k-1})$.

Comment: You did not specify the maps in your short exact sequence, which makes it lack context. Thankfully, the answer does not depend on what the maps are, as Zerox pointed out. The definition of splitting also requires that direct sum decomposition to be compatible with the maps in the sequence, but this too holds in the comment given by Zerox (which may as well be an answer).

Comment: @Zerox Why not an official answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most known result to show that a sequence splits is the splitting lemma.

**Splitting Lemma.** Let $$0\rightarrow A\overset{f}{\rightarrow} B\overset{g}{\rightarrow} C\rightarrow 0$$
be a short exact sequence in any abelian category. Then the following three statements are equivalent

1. There exists some left inverse $\tau:B\rightarrow A$ of $f$, that is $\tau\circ f=\text{id}_A$.
2. There exists some right inverse $\phi:C\rightarrow B$ of $g$, that is $g\circ\phi=\text{id}_C$.
3. The sequence splits, that is there is an isomorphism $\varphi:B\rightarrow A\oplus C$ such that the following diagram commutes. Hereby $i$ and $p$ are the canonical inclusion and projection respectively.
   $\require{AMScd}$
   \begin{CD}
   0 @>>> A @>f>> B @>g>> C @>>> 0\\
   @. @V \text{id}_A VV @VV \varphi V @VV \text{id}_C V @.\\
   0 @>>> A @>i>> A\oplus C @>p>> C @>>> 0\\
   \end{CD}

In addition to that the most basic general result you can use to show that your sequence splits probably is the following very useful Lemma.

**Lemma 1.** Every excat sequence of $\mathbb{Z}$-Modules
$$0\rightarrow A\overset{f}{\rightarrow} B\overset{g}{\rightarrow} C\rightarrow0$$
with $C$ a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module splits.

To prove this statement we will need the following Lemma.

**Lemma 2.** Let $\varphi:A\rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Further let $C$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then $\varphi$ is surjective if and only if for any homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $\psi:C\rightarrow B$ there is some $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism $\Psi:C\rightarrow A$ such that $\varphi\circ\Psi = \psi$, that is the following diagram commutes.
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} A @<\exists \Psi << C  \\ @V \varphi VV \swarrow_{\psi}  \\ B \end{CD}$$

*proof of Lemma 2.* "$\Rightarrow$" As $C$ is free we can choose a basis $(c_i)$ of $C$. If $\varphi$ is surjective, we can pick $a_i\in\varphi^{-1}(\left\lbrace \psi(c_i)\right\rbrace)$. Now define $\Psi:C\rightarrow A$ by $\Psi(c_i):=a_i$. Then the above diagram obviously commutes.
"$\Leftarrow$" Take $C=\mathbb{Z}$. Since we can define $\psi(1):=b$ for all $b\in B$, $\varphi$ obviously has to be surjective.

*proof of Lemma 1.* By exactness the homomorphism $g:B\rightarrow C$ is surjective. Consider the identity map on $C$, $\text{id}_C:C\rightarrow C$. Then by Lemma 2 there exists a homomorphism $\Psi:C \rightarrow B$, such that the following diagram commutes.
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} B @<\exists \Psi << C  \\ @V g VV \swarrow_{\text{id}_C}  \\ C \end{CD}$$
In particular $g$ has a right inverse since $g\circ\Psi=\text{id}_C$. Thus by the splitting lemma the sequence splits.

Comment: I am fine with getting downvotes for my post, but I would really appreciate if you could tell me what to improve in my post. I will do so!

Comment: I also don't get the downvotes, this sounds like a fine answer to me! It pretty much details Zerox's first comment on projectiveness without using the word projective. :)

Comment: Thank you! This precisely was my intention.